# Can't write XML to S3 from python lambda

Tags: python-3.x, xml, amazon-s3

I have a python lambda that takes a JSON  from my bucket and converts it to an XML file, I'm trying to then write the xml file back to an S3 and I seem to be doing it incorrectly. I've tried converting the element tree and the root to a string an every approach I take I seem to get some error in cloud watch.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would save XML file in a following way instead of `tree.write()`:

```
with open('tmp/data.xml', 'w') as file:
    file.write(ET.tostring(root).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: same cloud watch error "write() argument must be str, not dict" unfortunately :(

Comment: I take it back I think this is an acceptable solution, just seem to be having writing permissions problems now. 

Thank you for your solution.

Comment: getting this now "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied"

Comment: Seems to be an IAM issue. I would check permissions and in case problem cannot be found, ask a separate question about it.